# Remove duplicate codes in NSDictionary Params used for submission to server

Tags: objective-c, ios, duplicates, parameters

The code below shows the way I am preparing the params to be submitted to the server. I have a if-else clause to check and determine what params to submit i.e. if question id exists, submit only question id, else submit question text and topic id.

However, I feel that this is a little repetitive and not the best form of coding (in my POV). How can I refactor the code to make it more efficient (remove duplicate)

```
if(self.question._id || [self.question._id isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
    //Set up params for submission
    NSDictionary *params= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          self.answer.text, @"text",
                          //if question id exists, submit question id only 
                          self.question._id, @"question_id", 
                          shareFb, @"fbShare", 
                          shareTwitter, @"twitterShare",
                          self.question.source,@"questionSource",
                          self.answer.videoId,@"youtube_id",
                          nil
                          ];
}
else
{
    //Set up params for submission
    NSDictionary *params= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          self.answer.text, @"text", 
                          //else submit question text and topic id
                          self.question.text, @"question_text",
                          self.question.topic._id, @"topic_id", 
                          shareFb, @"fbShare", 
                          shareTwitter, @"twitterShare",
                          self.question.source,@"questionSource",
                          self.answer.videoId,@"youtube_id",
                          nil
                          ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mutable dictionary, then you can add in the extra fields

```
NSMutableDictionary *params= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
        self.answer.text, @"text",
        //if question id exists, submit question id only 
        self.question._id, @"question_id", 
        shareFb, @"fbShare", 
        shareTwitter, @"twitterShare",
        self.question.source,@"questionSource",
        self.answer.videoId,@"youtube_id",
        nil
        ];

if(!(self.question._id == nil || [self.question._id isEqual:[NSNull null]]))
{
    [params setObject:self.question.text forKey:@"question_text"];
    [params setObject:self.question.topic._id forKey:@"topic_id"];
}
```

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT 1

If any of the params being set in the first statement above might be nil, you will need to be more careful

```
NSMutableDictionary *params= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if (self.answer.text) {
    [params setObject:self.answer.text forKey:@"text"];
}
•
•  // all the params between self.answer.text and self.answer.videoId
•
if (self.answer.videoId) {
    [params setObject:self.answer.videoId forKey:@"youtube_id"];
}
if(!(self.question._id == nil || [self.question._id isEqual:[NSNull null]]))
    {
        if(self.question.text) {
            [params setObject:self.question.text forKey:@"question_text"];
        }
        if (self.question.topic._id) {
            [params setObject:self.question.topic._id forKey:@"topic_id"];
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot set nil object to key (ie `[params setObject:nil forKey:@"key]` will crash)

Comment: Is it ok to submit a 'null' or 'nil' object to server? I have the impression that everything after a'null' or 'nil' will not be considered for submission e.g. in my example, if question id is nil/null, all the subsequent params like shareFb, shareTwitter,youtube_id will be cut-off.

Comment: @Zhen yes, the first nil object will terminate the initWithObjectsAndKeys method.  I edited to show you how to get in each param that is not nil.  If you are populating these values from JSON, you might want to extend the if statements to check for isEqual:[NSNull null] how you do in the original question

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that I need to do a check first before setting the params in my case. Got it. Thanks!